# Bigquery: Aggregate ARRAY of STRUCTs in an Materialzed View

Tags: arrays, struct, group-by, google-bigquery, materialized-views

We are collecting error information from machines in BigQuery. Each error consists of two rows, one is written when the error occurred, the second when it was resolved. All error related information (error description, involved machine, meta information...) is compiled when the error occurs, i.e. in the first row. The second row, written when the error is resolved, contains mainly the timestamp of when it was resolved. Both rows share a common `errorIdentifier` that connects them.

The error messages and hints to solve the issue are available as `ARRAY`s  of `STRUCT`s (containing the language code as key and the error text as value). The error text itself is saved as an `ARRAY` of several textlines (due to historical reasons).

To clarify, the data structure looks like this:

```
  CREATE TEMP TABLE ErrorData ( 
    timestampOccurred TIMESTAMP,
    timestampResolved TIMESTAMP,
    machineId STRING,
    errorIdentifier STRING,
    errorDescription ARRAY<STRUCT<languageCode STRING, textlines ARRAY<STRING>>>,
    solution ARRAY<STRUCT<languageCode STRING, textlines ARRAY<STRING>>>
  );
  

INSERT INTO ErrorData 
VALUES(Timestamp('2024-02-12 10:0:0'), NULL, 'machine1', 'uuid-1', [STRUCT("en", ['en-line1', 'en-line2']), STRUCT("de", ['de-line1', 'de-line2'])], [STRUCT("en", ['en-line1', 'en-line2']), STRUCT("de", ['de-line1', 'de-line2'])]);

INSERT INTO ErrorData 
VALUES(NULL, Timestamp('2024-02-12 11:0:0'), NULL, 'uuid-1', NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO ErrorData 
VALUES(Timestamp('2024-02-12 11:30:0'), NULL, 'machine2', 'uuid-2', [STRUCT("en", ['en-line1', 'en-line2']), STRUCT("de", ['de-line1', 'de-line2'])], [STRUCT("en", ['en-line1', 'en-line2']), STRUCT("de", ['de-line1', 'de-line2'])]);

INSERT INTO ErrorData 
VALUES(NULL, Timestamp('2024-02-12 12:30:0'), NULL, 'uuid-2', NULL, NULL);
```

[image]

In order to further process the error data, I want to combine both rows into one. The final result of the example above should be:

[image]

Because we have tons of error data and the data does not change as soon as the error is resolved, I want to realize this using a (partitioned and clustered) Materialized View. However, I did not yet find a way to aggregate the `ARRAY`s of `STRUCT`s in the grouping process. `ANY_VALUE` was my first approach, but it can result in `NULL`, because there is no `IGNORE NULLS` for this operation. In my opinion, something like an `ANY_NON_NULL_VALUE` aggregation function would be needed for the error data. The definition of the Materialized View would then look something like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `project-id.dataset.my-mat-view` AS (
  SELECT
    MAX(timestampOccurred) AS timestampOccurred,
    MAX(timestampResolved) AS timestampResolved,
    MAX(machineId) AS machineId,
    errorIdentifier,
    ANY_NON_NULL_VALUE(errorDescription) AS errorDescription,
    ANY_NON_NULL_VALUE(solution) AS solution
  FROM
    `project-id.dataset.my-table`
  GROUP BY
    errorIdentifier)
```

Another idea was to use `ARRAY_AGG` in combination with `IGNORE NULLS` on the `UNNEST`ed arrays, but this operation is not supported to create Materialized Views.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?